# how do i use JS to show a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to coding and am working on an assignment. I have run into trouble with javascript. I am trying to create an order form. At the moment I cannot get the delivery address div to show when the radio button is checked. Being so new to this I cannot find where I have gone wrong!!! (I am trying to create the java script - task by task hence the mess).

```js
function show() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var delivery = document.getElementById("delivery");
  // Get the output text
  var show = document.getElementById("show");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display delivery address
  if (delivery.checked == true){
    show.style.display = "visible";
}
                
/* link HTML elements to corresponding event function */
function init () {
  var orderform =   document.getElementById("orderform");
  orderform.onsubmit = validate;
}

/* execute the initialisation function once the window loads*/
window.onload = init;
```

```css
#show {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="pickup">Pick-up</label>
        <input type="radio" name="deliverymethod" value="pickup" id="pickup"  />
    <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
        <input type="radio" name="deliverymethod" value="delivery" id="delivery" onclick="show()"/>
```

Thanks
Belinda

Comment: Recommend starting by fixing the console errors

Comment: You should use `show.style.display = "block";` in the if check

Comment: `document.getElementById("show")` there isn't an element with `id='show'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the String "visible" to "block" inside the final if should fix your problem. There is also a missing bracket '}' to close that final if.

**JS**

```
function show() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var delivery = document.getElementById("delivery");
  // Get the output text
  var show = document.getElementById("show");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display delivery address
  if (delivery.checked == true){
    show.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Not with all the other problems